# Subsampling from different distribution data?

Tags: statistics, numerical-linear-algebra, sampling, order-statistics, sampling-theory

I have a simple question. Thanks for helping me

Is there any difference between simple random subsampling a set with uniform distribution and a set with normal distribution?

How can I subsample in MATLAB from a set with uniform distribution such that the mean of subsampled is nonzero?

Comment: What is "the meaning of subsampled is nonzero" trying to say? MATLAB seems to have a function `randsample(sample,k)` which enables you to take a subsample of `sample` of size `k` without replacement, while  `randsample(sample,k,replacement)` may do something similar with replacement

Comment: I think the OP meant "mean" not "meaning".